# CNN classifier with keras shows accuracy (and categorical accuracy) of 1 but still many predictions are false

Tags: keras, deep-learning, classification, data-science, conv-neural-network

I have trained a CNN classifier and get weird results. When training, it reaches 1 accuracy (and also categorical accuracy, whatever the difference might be). However, when I predict on training samples manually, I rarely get the right class after a np.argmax() which seems very odd. I figured it might be a bad mapping of classes, but after checking the generator classes mapping it look ok.

I suspect the way I input the images for testing is different from the way the data generator feeds the images for training, it's the only possible explanation. Here's some code:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_classif_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory('full_ae_output/classifier_classes',target_size=image_dims_original, batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True, color_mode='grayscale')

classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=image_input_dims))
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))

#2nd convolution layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), padding='same'))
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))

#3rd convolution layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same'))
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))


# Classifier
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(n_classes*2,activation='relu'))
#classifier.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
classifier.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'))

classifier.summary()

classifier.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

> Epoch 1/3 92/92 [==============================] - 108s 1s/step -
> loss: 0.0638 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9853 Epoch 2/3 92/92

> [==============================] - 107s 1s/step - loss: 0.0141 -
> categorical_accuracy: 0.9969 Epoch 3/3 92/92

> [==============================] - 108s 1s/step - loss: 0.0188 -
> categorical_accuracy: 0.9938

```
input_class = 10
i = 0
image_path = glob.glob("full_ae_output/classifier_classes/class"+"{0:0=3d}".format(input_class)+"/*")[i]
input_img = np.array([np.array(Image.open(image_path).convert('L').resize(image_dims_original[::-1]))/255])
pred = classifier.predict(np.expand_dims(input_img,axis=3))
print("Predicted class = ",np.argmax(pred[0]))
```

I didn't recompute the actual accuracy but I suspect it to be lower than 50% since every sample I try I never get the right class.

Any ideas what might be bugging? Is the training accuracy computed by keras false?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! It's just a matter of interpolation, datagenerator uses nearest by default, and opencv.resize uses bilinear interpolation. It's unbelievable how this difference messes up the classifier and changes the whole predictions. Fixed it and I get my 100% accuracy right now. Issue solved!

Answer (score 0):

The training accuracy is definitely not false as computed by Keras.

Your intuition is good, indeed it is the preprocessing step on the test images that causes this problem.

I would recommend that you load one image and check how `ImageDataGenerator` works behind the curtains and check that when you use Pillow the exact preprocessing steps are applied.